# DOMDocument class not found even dom/xml extensions are installed and enabled

Tags: php, laravel

I'm currently having problem with DOMDocument Class not found on

https://github.com/tijsverkoyen/CssToInlineStyles/blob/0ed4a2ea4e0902dac0489e6436ebcd5bbcae9757/src/CssToInlineStyles.php#L111

It seems it can't read the domdocument extension.

I tried to create a test.php with

```
print_r(new \DOMDocument);
```

and it outputs the domdocument class.

**P.S**: I already have the xml libxml and dom extension on php. php version 7.3

php -m ( output )

```
[PHP Modules]
calendar
Core
ctype
date
dom
exif
fileinfo
filter
ftp
gettext
hash
iconv
imap
json
libxml
mbstring
mysqli
mysqlnd
openssl
pcntl
pcre
PDO
pdo_mysql
Phar
posix
readline
Reflection
session
shmop
SimpleXML
sockets
sodium
SPL
standard
sysvmsg
sysvsem
sysvshm
tokenizer
wddx
xml
xmlreader
xmlwriter
xsl
Zend OPcache
zip
zlib

[Zend Modules]
Zend OPcache
```

error in logs

```
[2019-08-28 04:39:06] local.INFO: Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError: Class 'DOMDocument' not found in /vendor/tijsverkoyen/css-to-inline-styles/src/CssToInlineStyles.php:111
```

here's the image of domdocument print_r

[image: print_r domdocument]

Comment: What is the php version that you used? how did you know that you already have  xml and dom extentions installed? have you trued `php -m` command to see the extention modules

Comment: Can you also post the actual error message.

Comment: I used php 7.3 and yes xml and dom are in the modules and can print_r(new \DOMDocument);

Comment: my best guess is that you're using php-cli to check if you have the XML extension installed & enabled, but you're using something else (perhaps php-fpm or mod_php?) when you get the error, and you have xml enabled in php-cli but not in that other thing, whatever it is.